# Navigation in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, navigation, routes

How does navigation work in Codeigniter?

I have a very simple use case

I have a link which on click should take me to a new page

```
<a href ="<?php echo site_url("/blog/create"); ?>">Create Post</a>
```

I have defined a function called create in my controller page (blog.php).This would contain the logic to display the createpost page.

```
public function create()
    {   
    }
```

I have setup the route in routes.php page like this

```
$route['create'] = "blog/create/";
```

Every time i click the link now i always **get the error that the requested url was not found on the server.**
What am i doing wrong here??
I am not able to get around this issue? Can some one help?

Note:
I have done the required changes in .htaccess file in order to remove the index.php file

Comment: Try base_url(), rather.

Comment: `siteurl()` is for navigation, `base_url()` is for loading assets, css, js, etc... so in that point he is doing right

Comment: site_url: Returns base_url + index_page + uri_string
and   base_url: Returns base_url + uri_string

Comment: You should have loaded the url_helper in your controller construct method or in the function that calls your view like this $this->load->helper('url') and then in your view you should echo the site_url()

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to touch **routes** if your controller/method isn't different one you wish to provide for routing.

Your controller should be something like:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller{

    public function create()
    {
        echo 'you have arrived on blog/create page';
    }

}
```

Now to access your page, you can go to your url which should be either

- `website.dev/blog/create`
- `website.dev/index.php/blog/create`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your your `.htaccess` file for any error. The rewrite rule from the manual does the job:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
   ```
2. in your config file remove `index.php` in this line:

   ```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```
3. make sure your controller has the correct syntax like:

   ```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Blog extends CI_Controller {

     public function create(){
       echo 'hello';
     }

   }
   ```

now either clicking on your link or typing the urls `localhost/blog/create` and `localhost/index.php/blog/create` will show whatever you output with your controller function `create()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify and just use:

```
anchor('controller/method');
```

There's no need to force the site url etc. CI can do that on it's own.